# A1181: How to run ASD or AHT on this macbook?

Tags: macbook-pro, apple-hardware-test

I have Lion installed on this 2007 macbook. OS was installed from A1384 USB drive.

How do I run AHT (or ASD) on this macbook? I tried hitting / holding "D" during normal bootup and it will start normally. When inserting the stick it will run into Install screen with no options or menus for AHT/ASD.

Is there a source for a CD/DVD to burn with those tools?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only official source, if you have lost your original OS X DVDs is to purchase one from the [Apple Store](http://www.apple.com/shop/product/D6106Z/A/os-x-lion)

Later models have the Hardware Tests built into ROM, earlier ones must use those on the DVD.

If you've got a [physical] Apple Store near you, they're usually quite obliging for that kind of thing.

Comment: This means, AHT is not on an original A1384 USB stick?

Comment: That stick is for a MacBook Air [first Mac without a SuperDrive] as far as I can tell, & that's the only machine it's likely to run properly on. For everything else prior to that, there's the DVD. From[AppleKB:OS X Mountain Lion: Use Apple Diagnostics or Apple Hardware Test](https://support.apple.com/kb/ph11342) - "Important: Follow these instructions only if your Mac came with a system software disc or USB flash drive. Do not try to use a disc or USB flash drive from another Mac model."

Comment: Annoyingly my macbook doesn't want to boot from an original 10.6 DVD.

Comment: Original to that precise model, or the generic retail should work [assuming the superdrive hasn't got hinky over the years, they do, unfortunately]. Specific to another model, no dice.

Comment: Original 10.4 doesn't work either. Apparently the superdrive has some issue. No matter how hard I hit the D-button at startup it won't boot into the DVD. Will it work with an external firewire drive?

Comment: Judging by the KB page, I'd say no... but there's a remote possibility "You may be able to start Apple Hardware Test from the Internet. Reconnect your Mac to the network, then restart your Mac while holding down both the Option and D keys."

Comment: It worked. I was able to boot into AHT from a 10.4 disk in a laCie drive connected via firewire. Interestingly AHT was on disk 1 other than stated in the Apple usage description. According to it it was supposed to be on disk 2. Nevertheless, AHT ran through and revealed no problem. Unfortunately I still don't know what's slowing down my macbook.